# Shiny and ggplot2 script issue

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Hello i have this quite simple script i can't make to work... it give me a histogram but not for the variable i asked for !
For example when i choose the variable AGE it doesn't show the the histogram of the AGE on the population but the total population : it s very likely it selects all the column of dat instead of dat$AGE but i can't find the solution

server.R :

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  dat <- reactive({
    req(input$df)
    dfile <- read.csv(input$df$datapath)
    updateSelectInput(session,inputId = 'select1', label = 'Variable',
                      choices = colnames(dfile))
    return(dfile)
    })



  output$data <- renderUI({
   if (!is.null(input$df$datapath)){
    selectInput('select1', choices = names(dat()), label = h3('Variable'))
   }
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlotly( ggplotly(
      ggplot(data=dat(),aes(x=input$select1))  + geom_histogram(stat = "count")))
  })
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("df","CSV file :"),
        uiOutput("data")
),

      mainPanel(
        h2(plotlyOutput("plot"))
      )
 )
 ))
```

If you can help, i searched for this all the afternoon :3

Answer (score 1):

In your call to `ggplot`, change the `aes` mapping to

```
aes_string("x" = input$select1)
```

since `input$select1` is a string.  In other words, your original code does `aes(x = "AGE")` rather than `aes(x = AGE)`, which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much